# How to plot similarly named columns using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, plot

I've read in some csv files using pandas. For now it's only two files, but in a few weeks I'll be working with several hundred csv files with the same data variables.

I've used a for loop to read in the files and appended the dataframes to a single list, and then used this for loop to differentiate the names some:

```
for i, df in enumerate(separate_data, 1):
    df.columns = [col_name+'_df{}'.format(i) for col_name in df.columns]
```

My question is this, how can I compare the variables between the files using a bar plot? For example, one of the common variables is temperature, so after differentiating the column names I now have temp_df1 and temp_df2. How would I go about calling all temperature columns to compare them in a bar plot?

I tried using this, but could not get it to work:

```
for df in separate_data:
    temp_comp = separate_data.plot.bar(y='temp*')
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compare between the two of them? What is the x axis of the plot?

Comment: How do you want to compare them? Is each bar an aggregate for a file or it it a separate bar plot for each file?

Comment: The x-axis is the months, 1-12. I just want to compare the monthly averages of the variables at the locations. So just the time on the x-axis and both temperature columns on the y-axis.

Comment: And each bar is an aggregate for a file. I'll create multiple bar plots, but that is comparing different variables. So like, one bar plot comparing temperatures, one comparing precipitation, and one comparing humidity. Each bar within the plot will represent a file for now.

Comment: Are you able to change how you read the file? Reading into one dataframe with an identifier column would make this a lot easier than multiple frames.

Comment: I could try that. I'm not sure how exactly to go about that, however! Any tips?

Comment: I've added an answer below. You might want to draw out what you want to see as hundreds of files with 12 months each seems like it could be quite a busy graph which would make it hard to see which file is which. Perhaps you could use something like a box plot to show the range or an interactive plot using plotly if you need individual marks. Depends on what you want to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have the three dataframes below, each with a temp column.  Here is how you iteratively combine the temp columns into a single new dataframe and plot them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'temp':[100,150,200], 'pressure': [10,20,30]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'temp':[50,70,100], 'pressure': [10,25,40]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'temp':[110,80,120], 'pressure': [8,20,50]})
df_list = [df1,df2,df3]

df_combined = pd.DataFrame()
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df_combined[f'df{i+1}'] = df['temp']
print('Combined Dataframe\n', df_combined)

df_combined.plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.ylabel('Temp')
plt.show()

#Combined Dataframe
    df1  df2  df3
0  100   50  110
1  150   70   80
2  200  100  120
```

[image]

Note that this assumes that all your dataframes have the same length. If this is not true, you can just read the first n (e.g. 50) rows from each dataframe to ensure equal lengths with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', nrows=50).
```

Comment: You are welcome.  Note that this assumes that all your dataframes have the same length.  If this is not true, you can just read the first n rows from each dataframe to ensure equal lengths with df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', nrows=50).

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would read into one data frame with an identifier to make the aggregation easier. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

filenames = ["file_1.csv", "file_2.csv"]

df = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.read_csv(filename).assign(filename=filename.split(".")[0])
        for filename in filenames
    ]
)

df.groupby("filename")["column_to_plot"].mean().plot.bar()
```